# configuring tasks.json in visual code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Trying to configure `tasks.json` in such a way that it transpiles and runs the JS code. But not sure how to do that. 
Also, whenever I try to (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), VS code tells me:

> No task is marked as a build task in tasks.json. Mark a task with 'isBuildCommand'

`tasks.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent", 
    "isBuildCommand": true,
    "args": ["--target", "ES5",
         "--outDir", "js",
         "--sourceMap",
         "--watch",
         "app.ts"],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the configuration. Is your `tasks.json` file inside `.vscode` folder?

Comment: yes it is inside .vscode folder

Comment: just got a Windows reset and Im also getting this problem (never happened to me before). I believe it should be some kind of bug.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you miss the **tasks** array in your configuration. Here is an example from [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks)

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "echo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "hello",
            "args": ["Hello World"]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "bye",
            "args": ["Good Bye"]
        }
    ]
}
```

In your case, it might be something like.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks":[
        {
           "isBuildCommand": true,
           "args": ["--target", "ES5",
                    "--outDir", "js",
                    "--sourceMap",
                    "--watch",
                    "app.ts"],
           "problemMatcher": "$tsc",
           "showOutput": "silent"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bug.

Closing and reopening the window temporarily solved it.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24796